# Unexpected token error while passing argument for the "onchange" method in input type file?

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-firestore

I added the input file tag dynamically and implemented onchange method by passing two arguments one is this(files info) and other is document id of the firestore collection. When the document id starts with number it is showing error but when the document id starts with alphabet it is working perfectly.

```
   db.collection("DialogflowChatRoom").doc(userid).collection("Earlyyears").orderBy("Time")
            .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
                var store_row = document.createElement("questions");
                var store;
                $('#questions').empty();
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                store = document.createElement("div");
                store.setAttribute("id", doc.id);
                store.setAttribute("class", "card no-border");
                // store.setAttribute("onClick", "select_user(this.id, '" + questionnumber + "', '" + time + "')");
                store.innerHTML = `<div class="container1">
                            <img src="assets/images/image 209.png" alt="Avatar" class="right" style="width:100%;">
                            <input type="file" id="files" onchange="handleFileSelect(this,` + doc.id + `)" onclick="this.value=null;"  accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png image/heic video/mp4" multiple>
                            </div>`;
                store_row.append(store);
                document.getElementById("questions").innerHTML = store_row.innerHTML;
                });
            });

   function handleFileSelect(e,docid) {
            console.log("values in handlefileselect are",e.files,docid.id)
            var id = docid.id
     }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing parenthesis around the ID. When the ID starts with a number that leads to a syntax error, as in your screenshot. But even when the ID starts with a letter it won't work, it just won't show until you run the code.

The solution is to enclose the ID in quotes:

```
handleFileSelect(this, '` + doc.id + `')"
```

Or (since you're already using backticks):

```
handleFileSelect(this, '${doc.id}')"
```